# Corona Runtime Error "attempt to concatenate field '?' (a nil value)"

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i have this 8 question survey in my mobile application handover project. At first the corona did not prompt me any error message and the app works just fine but when i add 2 more question to it i start getting this message error
[image]
i am not sure why the error is "a nil value" but my code look something like this.(line 662 to 678)

```
        function  checkEBASComplete()
        local tempScore = 0
        for i = 1, 10 do
            print("EBAS:"..ebasRating_Arr[i])
            tempScore = tempScore + ebasRating_Arr[i]

            if (ebasRating_Arr[i] == -1) then
                ebasScore = 0
                ebasScore_text.text = "Test Incomplete"
            else
                ebasScore = tempScore
                ebasScore_text.text = tostring(ebasScore)
            end

        end

        tempScore = 0
    end

    checkEBASComplete()
```

and i have something like this at line 110. i just add 2 more "-1" behide

```
 local ebasRating_Arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
```

Is anyone able to help me with this? Appreciate for all helps :D

NEW QUESTION------------------------------------------------------

[image]
this is my code from line 705 - 711

```
function saveResults()

        local q = [[UPDATE EBAS_DEP SET rating1=']]..ebasRating_Arr[1] .. [[',rating2=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[2] .. [[',rating3=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[3] .. [[',rating4=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[4] .. [[',rating5=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[5] .. [[',rating6=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[6] .. [[',rating7=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[7] .. [[',rating8=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[8] .. [[',rating9=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[9] .. [[',rating10=']] .. ebasRating_Arr[10] .. [[',rating11=']] .. amtRating_Arr[1] .. [[',rating12=']] .. amtRating_Arr[2] .. [[',rating13=']] .. amtRating_Arr[3] .. [[',rating14=']] .. amtRating_Arr[4] .. [[',rating15=']] .. amtRating_Arr[5] .. [[',rating16=']] .. amtRating_Arr[6] .. [[',rating17=']] .. amtRating_Arr[7] .. [[',rating18=']] .. amtRating_Arr[8] .. [[',rating19=']] .. amtRating_Arr[9] .. [[',rating20=']] .. amtRating_Arr[10] .. [[',rating21=']] .. amtRating_Arr[11] .. [[',ebas_score=']] .. ebasScore ..[[',amt_score=']] .. amtScore ..  [['WHERE id=']].. _G.EBAS_ID..[[';]]
        db:exec( q )
        print(db:errcode(), db:errmsg())

    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs when your `ebasRating_Arr` is too short for the for-loop inside the `checkEBASComplete`-function. Your original table has only 8 entries but your for-loop checks 10 entries of the table. That means the moment you attempt to access the 9. entry the error occurs because it doesn´t exist.

I would recommend changing the fixed for-loop from `1 to 10` to a relative for-loop `1 to the end of the array`. This would work with the `#array` (or table in Lua) operator. Your code would look like this:

```
function checkEBASComplete()
    local tempScore = 0
    for i = 1, #ebasRating_Arr do       -- Changed to relative for-loop
        print("EBAS:"..ebasRating_Arr[i])
        tempScore = tempScore + ebasRating_Arr[i]
        if (ebasRating_Arr[i] == -1) then
            ebasScore = 0
            ebasScore_text.text = "Test Incomplete"
        else
            ebasScore = tempScore
            ebasScore_text.text = tostring(ebasScore)
        end
    end
    tempScore = 0
end
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help it works but it throw me to another error that is similar. i will add it in the post please tell me where i gone wrong. Really appreciate your help

Comment: It is the same mistake again :D You are trying to access the table in a position that just don´t exists... You can prevent that by writing a simple `if-statement` before this query or by looping (for loop from answer) over the results and adding them to the `q` string. If you have further questions please post them as separate questions.

Comment: okay got it thanks for your help!! reallyyy appreciate it :DD

Comment: sorry to ask again, does it mean that i did not create my table properly? because im sure that i have question 1 to 10 in my database. still a little confuse

Comment: As I don't know how you created the table, I can't tell. But your problem was the following: You have a table with `n` entries. `n` in this case could be 9 or 10 or 8 values as you check the table whether it got all 10 or not (`checkEBAScomplete` function). It could be complete (10) or not (9). If it's complete then the you can go through the values 1 to 10 and everything works just fine. But you also want to go through the table if it isn´t complete. In case it got 9 entries you can't iterate from 1 to 10 but have to iterate to the ninth value because 10 just doesn't exist.

Comment: hi, i have solved this problem thanks for your help. is it possible for you to take a look at my another question about corona. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201469/corona-textbox-loop-into-database      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184075/corona-coverting-radio-button-to-numeric-textbox-lua     basically both of them is the same question but put in different way. if you are unsure you can commment in the post (link above)

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Sure thing :)