# corona coverting radio button to numeric textbox (lua)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create a mobile application about healthcare. I have to create a survey like application to screen the patients. Right now i have completed a part of the survey using radio button, the other part also look something like this(see picture below) but i want the radio button change to numeric textbox. 
My application look something like this:

[image: radio button]

Right now I want to convert the radio button to a numeric textbox.
The question is: how can i make minimum code changes and replace all the radio button to numeric textbox?

Here is my code for the radio buttons:

```
local radioGroup = display.newGroup()

    if(ebasRating_Arr[i] == 0) then
        radioButton_0 = widget.newSwitch {
            left = 565,
            style = "radio",
            initialSwitchState = true,
            id = tostring(i),
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating0
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_0 )

        radioButton_1 = widget.newSwitch {
            style = "radio",
            id = tostring(i),
            initialSwitchState = false,
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating1
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_1 )

    elseif (ebasRating_Arr[i] == 1) then
        radioButton_0 = widget.newSwitch {
            left = 565,
            style = "radio",
            initialSwitchState = false,
            id = tostring(i),
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating0
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_0 )

        radioButton_1 = widget.newSwitch {
            style = "radio",
            id = tostring(i),
            initialSwitchState = true,
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating1
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_1 )
    else
        radioButton_0 = widget.newSwitch {
            left = 565,
            style = "radio",
            initialSwitchState = false,
            id = tostring(i),
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating0
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_0 )

        radioButton_1 = widget.newSwitch {
            style = "radio",
            id = tostring(i),
            initialSwitchState = false,
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating1
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_1 )
    end

    radioButton_0.y = 150 + (i * 450)
    radioButton_1.x = 18 + radioButton_0.x+radioButton_0.width
    radioButton_1.y =  150 + (i * 450)
    scrollView:insert( radioGroup )

end
```

Comment: What do you mean with "numeric textboxes"? Do you want to create a range with 0-10 buttons? Or do you want to create a textfield where the user can manually put in a number?

Comment: just a text field. we can continue the conversation on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201469/corona-textbox-loop-into-database?noredirect=1#comment83386793_48201469